# Linux: dynamic loader selecting the wrong library?

Tags: linux, svn, shared-libraries, ldd

I run two versions of subversion on my system, using different libraries. This worked until yesterday, with the old version picking up the system libraries in `/usr/lib64`, and the new version picking up the new libraries in `~/local/lib`, but this has now broken.

The old version was installed with the distro, and I built the new one from source a few months ago. I built the new one in `~/local`, with the new binary in `~/local/bin/svn`, and the new libraries in `~/local/lib`. I also created a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, which included the single line `/home/me/local/lib`.

This worked fine until I tried to install Qt5 yesterday: I could run both the old Subversion (1.7.14), as `/usr/bin/svn`, and the new one (1.12.2), as `~/local/bin/svn`.

If I now try to run the old `svn` it tells me that there's a missing symbol in one of the Subversion libraries. If I run

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/svn
```

it turns out that the *old* `svn` now tries to load the *new* libraries in `~/local/lib`, so it doesn't work. Running `ldconfig` makes no difference. The old and new libraries are completely different, but somehow have the same version number:

```
$ ll /usr/lib64/libsvn_client-1.so.*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     24 Jan  3 11:37 /usr/lib64/libsvn_client-1.so.0 -> libsvn_client-1.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 379656 Nov 20  2015 /usr/lib64/libsvn_client-1.so.0.0.0
$ ll /home/me/local/lib/libsvn_client-1.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 me me      24 Oct  8 16:32 /home/me/local/lib/libsvn_client-1.so -> libsvn_client-1.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 me me      24 Oct  8 16:32 /home/me/local/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.0 -> libsvn_client-1.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 me me 2986816 Oct  8 16:32 /home/me/local/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.0.0.0
```

There's obviously something I don't understand about shared libs here. Presumably the dynamic loader selects the required library from the minor version numbers, but they're all `0` here. So how did this ever work? And surely `svn` doesn't ship with all-zero version numbers? Is it possible that the Qt5 install has caused a problem? Is there some way to fix this short of deleting one of the versions?

Comment: It might be tough to debug from your current situation, so I'd recommend getting your system back to working with the native version of svn first. I'm pretty sure adding that line to `/etc/ld.so.conf` is what broke your old version of svn. Comment out/remove that line, run `ldconfig`, and try running your old svn again. After that, it might be worth doing an `ldd` on your new version of of svn to see what it's trying to link against. If it's not linking against your built-from-source shared objects, you could create a wrapper that alters the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running.

Comment: Hi @wholevinski - removed the `ld.so.conf.d` file, and *both* the old and new versions now work. `ldd` on the new version still reports that it loads the new local libraries. `ldd` on the old version now reporting that it uses the old system libraries. So, head spinning - maybe the source build of `svn` used `rpath`, and so never used `ld.so.conf`... and maybe I forgot to run `ldconfig`?

Comment: The rpath linking sounds like a plausible theory. The only thing I can say for sure now though is that the line in your `ld.so.conf` was telling the linker to prioritize your local shared objects over your system ones, which is why removing it fixed the old one. As far as why the new version worked in both cases, I imagine you're right that the link paths are hardcoded somewhere, either using rpath linking or some other means.